# How to write to a file in a specific way by calling another function in python?

Tags: python, nlp

I have written log probability function in python that takes 2 words from a sentence as input, and returns the log probability. So, for e.g.: the sentence is: `STOP to be or not to be STOP`, I am converting the words having single occurrences to `<unk>` to get : `STOP to be <unk> <unk> to be STOP`, and then I'm getting its bigrams as:

```
['STOP,to', 'to,be', 'be,<unk>', '<unk>,<unk>', '<unk>,to', 'to,be', 'be,STOP']
```

My log probability function is as follows:

```
def logprob(self,context,event):
        str = context + " " + event
        list=[]
        list.append(str)
        c1 = self.m.count(str)
        v=len(self.l2)

        c2=self.trainfiles.count(context)
        c3=(c1+1.0)/(c2+v)
        self.prob=math.log(c3,2)
        return self.prob
```

So, if we do `logprob('STOP','to')`, we get `log(2/5)`

Now, I want to write another function that will write into a file like this:

```
STOP: STOP Log(1/5) to Log(2/5)  be Log(1/5)  <unk> Log(1/5)
to: STOP Log(1/6) to Log(1/6) be Log(3/6) <unk> Log(1/6)
be: STOP Log(2/6) to Log(1/6) be Log(1/6) <unk> Log(2/6)
<unk>: STOP Log(1/6) to Log(2/6) be Log(1/6) <unk> Log(2/6)
```

My prime concern is that I can't figure out how and where to call logprob in order to pass the words in it. If I call in main then it will only calculate the logprob value for that particular word, but I want to write a context with the logprobs of all its possible events. How should I do that?